# Select-Object Cmdlet Returns Different Formatted Results for Get-NetIPConfiguration (different type)

Tags: powershell

I was trying to get the IP config details for my physical network adapter, while excluding all virtual network adapter. My script is as below:

```
$NetAdaptIndex = Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Select -Property InterfaceIndex -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex

## Get Ip address, Gateway and DNS details as per configuration
$IPAddressConfig = foreach ($II in $NetAdaptIndex) {
    Write-Host $II -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    Get-NetIPConfiguration | 
        Where-Object { $_.InterfaceIndex -eq $II} |
        Select-Object InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDescription, InterfaceIndex, Ipv4Address, IPv4DefaultGateway, DNSServer
    }
```

When I call the variable, I get the following results where the IPv4Address, IPv4DefaultGateway, and DNSServer are not returned in a string format.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $IPAddressConfig


InterfaceAlias       : WiFi 2
InterfaceDescription : D-Link DWA-171 Wireless AC Dual Band Adapter
InterfaceIndex       : 46
IPv4Address          : {192.168.0.103}
IPv4DefaultGateway   : {MSFT_NetRoute (InstanceID = ":8:8:8:9:55?@55;C?8;@B8:8;55;")}
DNSServer            : {MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = "46", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "23"), MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = "46", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "2")}

InterfaceAlias       : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
InterfaceIndex       : 10
IPv4Address          : {169.254.149.208}
IPv4DefaultGateway   :
DNSServer            : {MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = "10", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "23"), MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = "10", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "2")}
```

But if I were to manually remove the Select-Object code, it returns a correctly formatted results.

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | 
        Where-Object { $_.InterfaceIndex -eq 46}
```

Observe how the IPv4Address, IPv4DefaultGateway, and DNSServer has returned the correctly formatted result.

```
InterfaceAlias       : WiFi 2
InterfaceIndex       : 46
InterfaceDescription : D-Link DWA-171 Wireless AC Dual Band Adapter
NetProfile.Name      : <removed>
IPv6Address          : <removed>
IPv4Address          : 192.168.0.103
IPv6DefaultGateway   : <removed>
IPv4DefaultGateway   : 192.168.0.1
DNSServer            : 2001:f40:0:3::12:68
                       2001:4860:4860::8888
                       1.1.1.1
                       8.8.8.8
```

My question is why is this happening? And is there any method that I can use to convert them to the correct format? The latter format are the one that I want.

Comment: Select-object changes the type from netipconfiguration to pscustomobject, but there's no such type to cast it back?

Comment: @js2010 Well, this quick and dirty hack didn't work: `(Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object ComputerName, DNSServer) | %{$_.PSTypeNames.Insert(0, 'NetIPConfiguration') ; $_}`

Comment: @beatcracker or this `Get-NetIPConfiguration | % { [pscustomobject]@{ipv4address = $_.ipv4address;dnsserver=$_.dnsserver;ipv4defaultgateway=$_.ipv4defaultgateway;pstypename='netipconfiguration'}}`

Comment: I've added a pseudo-answer below to explain what is the further steps that I've taken to reach the final solution. @beatcracker's answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the PowerShell is an object. The objects can get quite complex with multiple nested properties.

```
PS > (Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object DNSServer)[0]

DNSServer                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------                                                                                                                                                                                      
{MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = "11", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "23"), MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress (Name = "11", CreationClassName = "", Syste...

PS > (Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSServer)[0]

InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses                                                                                                                                 
                             Index     Family                                                                                                                                                  
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------                                                                                                                                 
LAN                                 11 IPv6    {}
```

To make your life easier, PowerShell formats objects when they're displayed on screen. Formatting rules are stored in the `xml` files: [Formatting File Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview). For the `NetTCPIP` module, the file would be `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP\Tcpip.Format.ps1xml`. Here is the `DNSServer` item formatting code:

```xml
<ListItem>
<Label>DNSServer</Label>
<ItemSelectionCondition>
    <ScriptBlock>
    ($_.DNSServer.Count -ne 0) -and
    (($_.NetIPv4Interface.ConnectionState -eq "Connected") -or
        ($_.NetIPv6Interface.ConnectionState -eq "Connected"))
    </ScriptBlock>
</ItemSelectionCondition>
<ScriptBlock>
    $output = "";
    foreach($Server in $_.DNSServer) {
    foreach($Address in $Server.ServerAddresses) {
        $output += $Address + "`n";
    }
    };
    $output.Trim("`n");
</ScriptBlock>
</ListItem>
```

What formatting gets applied is controlled by the `PSTypeNames` property which exists on every object:

```
PS > (Get-NetIPConfiguration)[0].PSTypeNames
NetIPConfiguration
System.Object
```

When you use `Select-Object`, it modifies that property, so the resulting object loses its formatting:

```
PS > (Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object DNSServer)[0].PSTypeNames
Selected.NetIPConfiguration
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Object
```

Alas, simply setting it back wouldn't work (object doesn't have correct structure for this), but you can emulate it by using [calculated property](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx):

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration  | Select-Object InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDescription, InterfaceIndex, Ipv4Address, IPv4DefaultGateway, @{ n='DNSServer' ; e={$_.DNSServer.ServerAddresses -join "`n"}}
```

This will squash `DNSServer` to string, so you wouldn't be able to reuse it properly later, though. Perhaps, just outputting `ServerAddresses` collection would be more convenient and it would look the same:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration  | Select-Object InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDescription, InterfaceIndex, Ipv4Address, IPv4DefaultGateway, @{ n='DNSServer' ; e={@($_.DNSServer.ServerAddresses)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the further read. This is the solution I'm using right now and only the DNSServer looks a bit weird since since everything is in one line. I'm joining the DNSServer with ''`n ", so that it at least has better readability.

Answer (score 1):

I've omitted to include that I'm piping the whole output to a ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet as not to make the question goes out of scope. But since I'm converting the output to HTML, it means that there is more than 1 way to skin the cat. I do not need to force the DNSServer object to be changed back to its previous formatting.

So, instead of joining the DNSServer with a ', ', I've joined it with a `<br>` tag instead.

```
Select-Object InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDescription, InterfaceIndex, @{n='IPv4 Address';e={$_.IPv4Address.IPAddress}}, @{n='IPv4 Default Gateway';e={$_.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop}}, @{n='DNS Server';e={$_.DNSServer.ServerAddresses -split " " -join "<br>"}}
```

Since ConvertTo-HTML translated the <> symbol to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, I've added the following code to translate `&lt;` and `&gt;` back to <>.

```
$IPAddressConfigTemp = $IPAddressConfig | ConvertTo-Html -fragment -As List -PreContent "<h2>IP Address Configuration Details</h2>"
$IPAddressConfigHTML = $IPAddressConfigTemp -replace "&lt;", "<" -replace "&gt;", ">" -replace "&#39;", "'"
```

The partial result of the code looks somewhat like this:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>DNS Server:</td><td>2001:f40:0:3::12:68<br>2001:4860:4860::8888<br>1.1.1.1<br>8.8.8.8</td></tr>
</table>
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it at least fits into what I would like to achieve. So, since I'm using calculated property to reach the final solution, I've selected @beatcracker's reply as the correct answer. It helps that his answer answered the whys and helped me to learn further.

Answer (score 0):

Using Select-Object with the -Property parameter results in a new object with a new type (Selected.NetIPConfiguration, pipe to Get-Member to see this).

Formatting in PowerShell is based on types, so the formatting is seeing the new type and not applying the formatting from the old type.

You could conceivably apply a new typename (using the PSTypeNames property), and copy the formatting instructions from the old typename (NetIPConfiguration) to the new one.

Note that the difference in formatting doesn't imply any difference in the property values, it's purely cosmetic.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to do further processing with the property values, so cosmetic is good enough and exactly what I want. I'll give it a try later to see if I could copy the old formatting over from the old typename.

Comment: I apologized to say that I don't need to do further processing with the property values. Since I'm piping the output to ConvertTo-HTML, so the above is not accurate. Sorry for the wrong info and thanks for your help.